# stuck thread in our Weblogic 10.3.3.0

Tags: java, weblogic

We are getting a stuck thread in our Weblogic 10.3.3.0.

```
Thread-465 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '33' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" <alive, suspended, priority=1, DAEMON> {
    java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1012)
    java.util.HashMap.buildCache(HashMap.java:581)
    java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:557)
    java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:936)
    java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:450)
    com.xyz.seeker.SpecialtyProvider.makeSpecialtyObjects(SpecialtyProvider.java:116)
    com.xyz.seeker.SpecialtyProvider.populateSpecialtyTree(SpecialtyProvider.java:91)
    com.xyz.seeker.SpecialtyProvider.getChildrenJson(SpecialtyProvider.java:74)
    com.xyz.seeker.SpecialtyProvider.doPost(SpecialtyProvider.java:42)
    com.xyz.seeker.SpecialtyProvider.doGet(SpecialtyProvider.java:36)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:700)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:815)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:224)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:108)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:206)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:61)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:25)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(Unknown Source)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(Unknown Source)
    weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:308)
    weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:117)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(Unknown Source)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(Unknown Source)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(Unknown Source)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:198)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:165)
```

Here is the code that is throwing this:

```
public Specialty makeSpecialtyObjects(final ResultSet rs) throws java.sql.SQLException{
    Specialty root = new Specialty();
    root.setId(ROOTID);
    root.setTitle("root");
    Specialty specialty;
    parentIdMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    specialtiesMap = new HashMap<String, Specialty>();
    parentIdMap.put(""+ROOTID,null);
    specialtiesMap.put(""+ROOTID,root);  << I think the exception is coming here.
    while (rs.next()){
        int id  = rs.getInt(1);
        String name = rs.getString(2).trim();
        int disabled  = rs.getInt(3);
        int primId  = rs.getInt(4);
        String primName = rs.getString(5).trim();
        int depId  = rs.getInt(7);
        String depName = rs.getString(8).trim();
```

Here is the Specialty class we have:

```
public class Specialty implements Serializable {
private String title;
private String id;
private List<Specialty> children;
private Specialty parent;
private boolean disabled;
```

Another person suggested that the issue may be the boolean primitive, but I think that is serializable.  I am not sure where I should look next.  We can only get this issue in production.

Comment: What is ROOTID? I'll assume its some static integer value? It could be useful to know what this value is

Comment: Additionally, the exception looks like the HashMap is having problems iterating over the key's of your map as it tries to copy the entries from the old HashMap into new bigger HashMap.

Comment: ROOTID is a static String value.

Comment: What is your Stuck Thread Max Time value for your weblogic server?

Comment: Our Weblogic server Stuck Thread Max time value is set at 600 seconds.

Comment: I was thinking it might have just been taking a long time, but clearly 600 seconds is well above what I would consider Hashmap taking a long time. I can't see anything wrong with the code snippets you posted. The fact specialtiesMap.put(""+ROOTID,root); is causing a re-size immediately following the HashMap creation is very confusing. I am certain the serialization will not have an affect, as nothing would be serialized in the code you have provided. Sorry, that's the best I can do.